# Log4Net Dynamic Filename not working with GlobalContext

Tags: configuration, logging, log4net

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [log4net file names based on GlobalContext properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/562108/log4net-file-names-based-on-globalcontext-properties)

This is really starting to bother me. I'm just simply trying to add a property variable to a log4Net filename. What am I doing wrong?

Here's the config:

```
 <appender name="logger1" type="log4net.Appender.FileAppender">
    <file type="log4net.Util.PatternString" value="C:\temp\file_%property{foo}.log" />
    <appendToFile value="true" />         
    <Layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
      <conversionPattern value="%newline%date --- %message%newline" />
    </Layout>    
 </appender>
```

And here's the code:

```
string foo= "bar";
log4net.GlobalContext.Properties["foo"] = foo;
_logger.ErrorFormat("test");
```

And the resulting log name is ***file-(null).log***

Anyone see anything that I'm missing here? Because otherwise it seems to me to be a bug.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/562108/log4net-file-names-based-on-globalcontext-properties).

You have to set the property before you create the logger.