# Separate log file for specific class instance using NLog

Tags: c#, .net, logging, nlog

I need to write event log for every instance of class to separate file. Historically project uses NLog for logging, so  I want to try resolving this issue using NLog (I've found similar topic [Unique log file for each instance of class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6191874/unique-log-file-for-each-instance-of-class) , but it's suggests using log4net)

Currently I'm getting instance of logger like this:

```
    public static Logger GetInstanceLogger(string name, bool init = false)
    {
        if (!LogManager.Configuration.AllTargets.Any(t => t.Name == name))
        {
            var target = new FileTarget();

                target.Name = name;
                target.FileName = string.Format("logs/{0}.${{shortdate}}.log", name);

            target.Layout =
           "${date:format=dd.MM.yyyy HH\\:mm\\:ss.fff} thread[${threadid}] ${logger} (${level:uppercase=true}): ${message}. ${exception:format=ToString}";
            var config = init ? new LoggingConfiguration() : LogManager.Configuration;
            config.AddTarget(name, target);

            var ruleInfo = new LoggingRule("*", LogLevel.Trace, target);

            config.LoggingRules.Add(ruleInfo);

            LogManager.Configuration = config;

            LogManager.ReconfigExistingLoggers();
        }

        var logger = LogManager.GetLogger(name);

        return logger;
    }
```

Right now it's writing same log into all files (I suppose it's caused by the log level). Is there a way to accomplish this task using NLog?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I came out with solution using event properties of layout renderer in the filename. When I'm writing new message to log, I'm adding filename as a property for LogEventInfo

```
protected virtual void SendEvent(LogLevel level, string message, Exception exception, string memberName = null)
    {
        var logEvent = new LogEventInfo(level, _name, message);
        logEvent.Exception = exception;
        foreach (String key in _properties.Keys)
        {
            logEvent.Properties[key] = _properties[key];
        }
        _logger.Log(logEvent);
    }
```

And in configuration file in NLog targets section:

```
  <targets async="true">
  <target xsi:type="File" name="f" fileName="${basedir}/logs/${shortdate}_${event-properties:item=Name}.log"
          layout="${detailedLayout}" />
  <target xsi:type="File" name="errorLogFile" fileName="${basedir}/logs/${shortdate}.ERROR_${event-properties:item=Name}.log"
      layout="${detailedLayout}" />
</targets>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
try var ruleInfo = new LoggingRule(name, LogLevel.Trace, target);
```